# Take input of two data without using space or enter

Tags: c++, input

In C it is very simple `scanf("%d : %d",&a,&b)` say input **5:10** . So here a=5 and b=10. (:)Just split them into two as a separate integer. How can we do in C++
without using space or enter between two input

```
int a,b;
cin>>a>>b; // how we take input two integer taking as 5:10
cout<<a<<b; // a=5 and b=10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char c;
    std::cin >> a // Read first number,
             >> c // oh, there is a character I do not need
             >> b; // and read second
}
```

Or if you do not like having to declare that spare variable, this also works.

```
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin.ignore(1);
    std::cin >> b;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter is only 1 `char` long:

- Calling `std::cin.ignore()`
- Using a temporary `char` variable `std::cin >> delimiter;`

Those solutions should be put after getting the first number (`std::cin >> a;`) and before getting the second number (`std::cin >> b;`).